# Arrow function object iteration with condition

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

This question is about improving working code. I have a function showLabels that takes a value, iterates over an object and defines which label to return by comparing the value to the object keys.

```
  showLabels = (value) => {
    Object.keys(this.state.labels).forEach( key => {
      if (value <= key) this.tooltip = this.state.labels[key];
    });
    return this.tooltip;
  }
```

The question: Is it possible to make this more succinct? Especially assigning the value of the function to this.tooltip and then returning it in the outer function seems unnecessarily verbose.

**Example**

Based on a comment here is an example:

```
this.state.labels = {0: "Smallest amount", 50: "In the middle", 100: "Top"}
value = 33
//showLabels(value=33) should return "In the middle"
```

Comment: can you show us and example of it running?like,what is value and the labels

Comment: Sure, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) on [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
 showLabels = value => Object.entries(this.state.labels)
                             // sort pairs by key
                             .sort(([keyA], [keyB]) => keyA > keyB)
                             .find(([key]) => key > value)[1]
```

BTW keep in mind that the order of iteration over keys is not guaranteed. So assuming you want to find the first label that is greater than value, you need to sort labels.

Comment: Great advice, also regarding the sorting. Am I right that Object.entries is in Draft state and therefore not recommendable to use in production apps? Is there another way without experimental language features?

Comment: @user2672106 There is [polyfill available](https://github.com/es-shims/Object.entries). Also you could iterate over keys `this.state.labels[Object.keys().find()]` And of course you could transpile your code using babel :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, Yury!

Answer (score 0):

```js
showLabels = (value) => {
  let tooltip, { labels } = this.state
  Object.keys(labels).forEach( key => {
    if (value <= key) tooltip = labels[key];
  })
  return tooltip;
}
```

Something like this is more succinct. Is there a reason you need to use `Object.keys()` here? It's rather slow.

Anyway, I've added a variable declaration and a destructuring in the beginning.